# Deploy Hubot on AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, hubot

I'm a noob using Hubot, so please bear with me.

I was going through Hubot's documentation ( https://hubot.github.com/docs/deploying/ ) and saw that we can deploy to Heroku, Unix systems and others.

May I know how can Hubot be deployed on AWS Lambda ?

Best Regards.

Comment: I don't think Lambda is what you're looking for. Amazon's equivalent for Heroku is Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: I see. thanks a lot! I just thought that since Hubot responds by "listening" it kindda work the same way as how Lambda functions can run. Does it make sense ?

Comment: I get your thinking but Lambda is for very short running processes. Hubot responds to events but is a long running process.

Comment: got it! u the MAN.

Answer (score 4):

I was wondering the same thing. I think the answer is probably "yes, if your chat system can send you http when traffic happens". I think Lambda is probably a great choice, since each message in chat is an event to process according to the rules that your bot has. So, the Lambda function invocation model is a good fit - lots of tiny invokes. You might, though, want to filter the traffic that gets to the function, though, if your chat system is high-traffic.

For example [Slack's Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) lets you subscribe to all of the things you might need the bot to see, I think. You'd then need to route those requests to your lambda function, which you could do via AWS API Gateway.

The existing [hubot-slack adapter](https://github.com/slackhq/hubot-slack) uses the Real-Time Messaging API, though, so you'd need to write your own adaptor for the Events API http that the API Gateway receives.

The same approach (and requirement) applies to other chat systems.